# Having trouble rendering a local PDF within a NextJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to show my resume (local file) within a react component but have been running into issues importing it.

`import myResume from '../assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf'` just gives me the error:

Cannot find module '../assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

and if I try to use the import like this:

```
import myResume from '../assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf'

function Resume() {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe src={myResume} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Resume
```

It gives me a failed to compile error:

./assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

I've also tried using the React-pdf package, but with the same results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually figured out a workaround, not sure if this is the correct way, but I was able to get it to work by just putting the src right in the iframe.

So instead of

```
import myResume from '../assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf'

function Resume() {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe src={myResume} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I just did

```
function Resume() {
  return (
    <iframe src='/assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf' />
  )
}
```

which seems to work well.

Comment: I had to remove the import statement.

Comment: Using Nextjs 13 app dir, this just downloads the object rather than letting you view it.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use `react-pdf` with Nextjs, one way to make it work is to pull `pdf.worker.js` from the CDN using:

```
import {pdfjs, Document, Page} from 'react-pdf'

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.min.js`
```

Then it seems to work fine with any URL to the PDF or file imported as you did.
For example,

```
<Document file={myResume}>
    <Page pageIndex={0}/>
</Document>
```

Ref: 
https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/136

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

Comment: It's weird that pageIndex works but pageNumber doesn't

Comment: This works perfectly with Next 13. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Put the file in the `public` folder.

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Your code can then reference files inside the public by starting from the base URL (/).

For example, if you add a pdf to public/resume.pdf, the following code will access the pdf:

```
<Link href="/FirstName_LastName_Resume.pdf">
   <Text>Hire Me?</Text>
</Link>
```

Comment: this didn't work... the page displays the following error: 404
This page could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

Next js looks for the files in the public folder put your assets folder in the public folder then use like this: src = "/assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf".
and don't include public folder in path because it automatically looks for it inside the public folder.

Comment: No luck, just get `Module not found: Can't resolve '/assets/pdfs/myResume.pdf'`, but it is able to find the favicon.ico with just '/favicon.ico'

Answer (score 2):

i used the native `<object>` tag (support)ie:

```
<object data="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>Unable to display PDF file. <a href="sample.pdf">Download</a> instead.</p>
</object>
```

- MozDocs:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object
- CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_object